# ggplot geom_line color based on a density function

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
i = rnorm(10000, 5, 1)
tb = tibble(x = i, y = i^2.5)
ggplot(tb, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(alpha = 0.09, size = 0.2)
```

[image]

For some reason, I need to show a line instead of individual points:

```
ggplot(tb, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Is it possible to use a **gradient color for the line** to resemble the **'density' of the original data points**, perhaps using a density function based on values on the `x` axis (e.g., `density(i)$y`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to estimate the density, then define the approximation function with `approxfun` and evaluate it at `x`. Then just use `scale_color_gradient`.

```
tb %>% mutate(Density = approxfun(density(x),rule=2)(x)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y,color=Density)) + geom_line() + scale_colour_gradient(low = "white", high = "black")
```

[image: Plot]